# How to un-normalize geo points in order to plot on leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Leaflet consists of multiple self worlds. General limit of latitude n longitude is `-90 to +90` and `-180 to +180` respectively. So for a different number of world in map area i receive `{lat: 76.12621315046384, lng: 370.70826412409673}`, which i normalize to the limit format and send as a param to server in order to receive points based on an algorithm. However the points that i receive are in normalized format already which will plot on the initial first map only, however i would like to plot them on that number of world on map area from which i retrieved longitude as `370.70826412409673`.

I tried getting getting pane, scaleZoom, zoomScale, scale, zoom but nothing seem to work in order to get me the world number or anything that helps me de-normalize the geopoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [getBounds()](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-getbounds) that gives you the coordinates of the two corners of the current view and/or [getCenter()](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-getbounds). You can then change your longitude to fit this view.

An other solution is to keep the offset between the normalized and "true" coordinates, and add it back to the answer of your algorithm.